# Ordering DISTINCT with string_agg using another column on PostgreSQL 13?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `emails` table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.emails (
  id                bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807),
  name  text not null
);
```

I have a `contacts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.contacts (
  id                bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807),
  email_id            bigint NOT NULL,
  full_name            text NOT NULL,
  ordering  int  not null
);
```

And records as follow:

```
insert into emails (name) VALUES ('dennis1');
insert into emails (name) VALUES ('dennis2');

insert into contacts (id, email_id, full_name, ordering) VALUES (5, 1, 'dennis1', 9);
insert into contacts (id, email_id, full_name, ordering) VALUES (6, 2, 'dennis1', 5);
insert into contacts (id, email_id, full_name, ordering) VALUES (7, 2, 'dennis5', 1);
insert into contacts (id, email_id, full_name, ordering) VALUES (8, 1, 'john', 2);
```

My query to fetch data as follows:

```
SELECT
  "emails"."name",
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CAST("contacts"."id" AS TEXT), ','
  ORDER BY CAST("contacts"."id" AS TEXT)) AS "contact_ids"
FROM "emails"
  INNER JOIN "contacts"
    ON ("contacts"."email_id" = "emails"."id")
WHERE "emails"."id" > 0
GROUP BY "emails"."name"
ORDER BY "emails"."name" DESC LIMIT 50
```

### Actual Result

```
name       contact_ids
dennis2    6,7
dennis1    5,8
```

### Expected Result

```
name       contact_ids
dennis2    7,6
dennis1    8,5
```

I want to order `contact_ids` based on `ordering` column as `DESC` but i do not want to fetch `ordering` column. Just use it to order id of contacts.

How can I sort `contact_ids`'s each `id` based on `ordering` column?

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4d6851ec67b579608427bb399eae5891

Comment: Why do you want to leave out the ordering column if you have one?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `ORDER BY CAST("contacts"."id" AS TEXT)` is a bad idea, because that would sort `10` before `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aggregate before joining, you don't need the DISTINCT and you are free to order by anything you want:

```
select em.name,
       c.contact_ids 
from emails em
  join (       
    select email_id, string_agg(id::text, ',' order by ordering desc) as contact_ids
    from contacts
    group by email_id
  ) c on c.email_id = em.id
order by em.name desc 
limit 50;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c63dbf1818d4128a99a6e3848e89e16b)

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. What If i want another column to be merged with comma? Lets say I want user_id field/column to be merged? In this case your result gives me duplicate user_id due to group. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=51ba9a6ba9b4a03e1b74bfbffe59bd54

Comment: @Dennis: well, obviously you need to include that additional column in the derived table, otherwise you can't use it for the join.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=355df539d7deb6b1727954a41b04bcc4)

I guess, leaving out the ordering column is because of the problem, that you cannot use it int the aggregation with `DISTINCT`.

So, possibly you can do the `DISTINCT` before aggregating:

```
SELECT
    "name",
    STRING_AGG(CAST("id" AS TEXT), ',' 
        ORDER BY "ordering") AS "contact_ids"
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON ("contacts"."id")
    "emails"."name",
    "contacts"."id",
    "contacts"."ordering"
  FROM "emails"
    INNER JOIN "contacts"
      ON ("contacts"."email_id" = "emails"."id")
  WHERE "emails"."id" > 0
  ORDER BY "contacts"."id"
) s
GROUP BY "name"
ORDER BY "name" DESC LIMIT 50
```